# Build performance Dagger2 vs Hilt

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

We have a large application with many modules.
There is a problem with the application build time, both the total time and the incremental time.

At the moment we are using Hilt as DI.
As you know, Hilt uses dagger subcomponents, which in turn does not allow parallel graph generation. But as I understand it, this is no longer a pressing problem?

I want to understand if it makes sense to switch from heal to dagger (using dependency components) to speed up the build time?
I have not found a single article comparing the build time of Dagger vs Hilt.

Do you have any such experience or thoughts?